Cucumber (Java) - Converting Checked Exceptions to Runtime Exceptions - Is this a good idea?
The testing framework that I am working on is based on Cucumber and Selenium in Java. The codebase contains a lot of base/common methods that perform certain actions and these methods throw checked exceptions (for operations such as File Reading or Parsing JSON payloads) - the checked exceptions in these methods are not handled using a try-catch block and are instead just thrown.
As a result, any method that calls these methods needs to throw that exception as well. This has resulted in a very 'polluted' codebase where almost every method is throwing an exception even when there is no connection between what the method does and what exception it is throwing, even when these methods are several layers 'above' the original method that is generating the exception.
As I understand it, in the end these checked exceptions are eventually handled by the Cucumber framework code itself - in that the test/scenario execution fails and the framework moves to the next test/scenario.
So, is it a good idea to use a try-catch block in the base/common methods that are generating the checked exceptions, and converting them to Runtime exceptions that fail the test that is being executed and moves on to the next test/scenario?
The way I see it, anytime such a checked exception occurs, the test is a failure and needs to be re-run anyways. Thus, with this technique, the checked exception is not thrown, and the 'throws' clause can be removed from all reliant methods thus making the codebase easier to read.

Ideally you'd also avoid the try-catch block to throw a new RuntimeException. This adds another exception to the chain and makes reading stack traces harder.
Rather you'd want to rethrow the exception as an unchecked exception.
For example in JUnit 5:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/3e6c876a4be3ce9498ad1dea4c89100640f663c9/junit-platform-commons/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ExceptionUtils.java#L72-82
And to avoid writing that yourself have a look at using Lombok. The @SneakyThrows annotation effectively turns checked into unchecked exceptions.

Thank you!

Ideally you'd also avoid the try-catch block to throw a new RuntimeException. This adds another exception to the chain and makes reading stack traces harder

So I have added helpful messages to these Runtime Exceptions as currently our logging is quite bad and random. I did know about @SneakyThrows but since you cannot add a String message to it AFAIK I have chosen not to use it, although it would make the codebase more concise and easy to parse.
